# ExpressJs receiving empty string fields which must have been objects and arrays

Tags: node.js, express, multipartform-data, multer, form-data

My backend:
middlewares:

```
const middlewares = [
  cors(),
  helmet(),
  morgan('dev'),
  compression(),
  express.json(),
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
    limit: '15MB',
  }),
]

const app = express()
middlewares.forEach((middleware: any) => app.use(middleware))
```

Router:

```
const createCompany = multer({
  limits: {
    fileSize: MEGABYTES_TO_BYTES(15), // returns 15 MB in KB
  },
}).fields([
  { name: 'media', maxCount: 5 },
  { name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'mainImage', maxCount: 1 },
])

Router.post(
  '/company',
  createCompany,
  async (req: any, res, next) => {
    console.log('occupations', typeof req.body.occupations, req.body.occupations.length)
//other stuff
})
```

The `console.log('occupations', typeof req.body.occupations, req.body.occupations.length)` shows me:

**ocupations string 0**

And here is my front-end:

```
 const url = '/business/company'

  const data = new FormData()

  const occupations = ['one', 'two', 'three']
  data.append('occupations', occupations)
  
  const logo = {
    uri: logoURI,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: Math.random().toString(),
  }
  data.append('avatar', logo)


  return http.post(url, data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
```

I cannot receive **occupations** field in normal object type format, it is string and it happens with **'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'**

What is wrong?

**Thank you mates in advance!**

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are not accessing the body of the request actually.

You should use `req.body.occupations` instead of `occupations` to access the data sent to you from the front-end.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I know about that. My fault that I didnt specify how I retrieve occupations field. I edited the post now